# How to us an arg given to Flask app.config inside a route function?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, queue

My webapp runs from inside a function because im multithreading with other functions (only 1 instance of flask), and my questions are:
A. What is the best way to pass a Queue into the app? 
B. When passed, how can the Queue be used inside a specific route?

Here is the relevant part of the code ive written so far, which gives and error "global name 'queue' is not defined" when a request is made to "/parser".

```
app = Flask(__name__)
q = Queue()
app.config['queue'] = q;

@app.route('/parser')
def Parser():
    arg = request.args.get('arg') #if key doesn't exist, returns None
    queue.put(arg)

def Run():
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    app.config['queue'] = q;
    thread = Thread(target = Run)
    thread.start()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Added a code sample that might be of help

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

app = Flask(__name__)
q = Queue()
app.config['queue'] = q;
app.config['test'] = 'testing';

@app.route('/insert/<var>')
def Insert(var):
    q = app.config['queue']
    q.put(var)
    return "Ok"

@app.route('/pop')
def Get():
    q = app.config['queue']
    return q.get()


def Run():
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target = Run)
    thread.start()
```

I am pretty sure that flask does not support running the same app instance in multiple threads.

I have a feeling that this is an instance of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.), 
If you are deploying on production, this [page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/) lists some ways to do so that can handle multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: I didnt run multiple flasks, the other threads are doing completely different things. My question isn't really about Queues, it's about using an arg sent through app.config, in one of it's routes.